# Prevent hotlinking from harassing domain by showing an image or iframe? .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've some site that keep stealing my images and sometime even iframe to get my content.

I've tried using .htaccess to redirect any images that stolen to image like `stop hotlinking` but I still get the same problem they get around it like using something not to give an extension like .jpg .gif .png or something

is there anyway that I can edit .htaccess to prevent this happening by showing an iframe instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the following? :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_rewrite-hot-linking-images-leeching-howto/

http://underscorebleach.net/jotsheet/2004/11/stop-image-hotlinking-tutorial-htaccess-apache

http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html

-or-

http://bit.ly/ImCQOa